# Running a background service when app is not active in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create a service which periodically performs a function and calls another function when certain requirements are met. All of this should happen in the background process.

this is onPause method of my main acivity where I start the service which is supposed to perform the task required:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
        if(alarm){
            bgIntent = new Intent(this, bgAlarmService.class);
            startService(bgIntent);
            alarmHostIsService = true;
        }

    }
```

onStartCommand of my service:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(bgAlarmService.this)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(bgAlarmService.this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(bgAlarmService.this)
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .build();
                }

                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        };

        Thread bgThread = new Thread(r);
        bgThread.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

but when the onPause method is called and app becomes inactive, the service does'nt continue working. How do I run this service in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use service and broadcast receiver to do that .
At fix time interval send brodcast using following code .

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentDateTime=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.setTime(new Date(currentDateTime+(5*60*1000)));// 5 minutes timeout
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,YourReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

inside your broadcast receiver now start service inside onStartCommand.

```
Intent yourService= new Intent(context, YourService.class);
context.startService(Intent yourService= new Intent(context, YourService.class);
```

Comment: Oh gosh, why 5 minutes lag calculation is so complicated?:)

Comment: I have this one if you know simpler plz comment , I will add that to my knowledge base.

Comment: use `System.currentTimeMillis() + 5* 60 * 1000` ;) instead of so huge calculations.

Comment: Yes. you need to remove that statement.

Comment: What if android decides to call onStop() method of my app while it is in minimized form? Does that even matter?

Comment: even if you are minimizing your app you will be calling sending broadcast to run the service after fix amount of time.